# Datagridviews row count?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have this 2 Datagridviews, dgv1 and 2. How can i check if dgv2 has no "content" or rows?

For example i want to do: Send OrderID: 0001(from dgv1) to archives if dgv 2 is "empty" or no rows? basically i want to remove this Order is its dgv2 has no rows or no products left.

dgv2's content is related to dgv1's primary key btw.
[image]

```
     private void dgvReceiving_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-MQKIBSK\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MARISCHELLdatabase;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            SqlCommand command =
            new SqlCommand("select OrderID,SupplierName,LeadTime,OrderedBy,DateOrdered,Status,DateToReceived from Orders where OrderID = '" + dgvReceiving.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'", connection);
            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (read.Read())
            {
                rorderid.Text = (read["OrderID"].ToString());
                rsupplier.Text = (read["SupplierName"].ToString());
                rleadtime.Text = (read["LeadTime"].ToString());
                rordered.Text = (read["OrderedBy"].ToString());
                rdateordered.Text = (read["DateOrdered"].ToString());
                rdatedelivery.Text = (read["DateToReceived"].ToString());
                rstatus.Text = (read["Status"].ToString());

            }


            SqlConnection cn2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-MQKIBSK\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MARISCHELLdatabase;Integrated Security=True");
            cn2.Open();
            string amt = "select sum(TotalPrice) from Orders_productholder where OrderID = '" + rorderid.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(amt, cn2);
            labelsupertotal.Text = "P "+cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }

        dgvreceivingproduct();

    }

    private void dgvreceivingproduct()
    {  
       SqlConnection cn3 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-MQKIBSK\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MARISCHELLdatabase;Integrated Security=True");
        cn3.Open();
        string qry = "Select Status,ID,ProductID,ProductName,Dosage,Price,QtyOrdered,TotalPrice,ExpirationDate,SellingPrice,BatchNumber from Orders_productholder where Status = 'Unreceived' and OrderID = '" + dgvReceiving.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "' ";
        SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(qry, cn3);
        DataTable poholder = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd3);
        adapter.Fill(poholder);

        dgvReceivingproducts.DataSource = poholder;
    }
```

Comment: Cast your datasource and count that way.  For example, if it's a DataTable: DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
                int i = ((DataTable)dgv.DataSource).Rows.Count; .... If it's something else, cast the same and use the object's "count" function.

Comment: If you aren't looping, use an `if (read.Read()) {`.  Use sql parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting issues.

Answer (score 1):

use the property `(dgv2.RowCount > 0)`

Comment: An empty grid might still have that "new row" line showing, which would count as a row.